# globals(), locals() and import

Tags: python, import, compilation, global, local-variables

I come across this tricky import problem, which I believe related to the global() and locals() environment, but cannot figure out all details. With three files in the same directory, the first is main.py:

```
class Bnk():
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name
    def __str__(self):
        return 'Bnk instance ' + self.name

with open('B.py') as f:
    code = compile(f.read(), 'B.py', 'exec')
    exec(code)

with open('A.py') as f:
    code = compile(f.read(), 'A.py', 'exec')
    exec(code)
```

The second is A.py:

```
A = Bnk('A')
print(A)

from B import B
print(B)
```

The third is B.py:

```
B = Bnk('B')
print(B)
```

The output of python main.py is:

```
Bnk instance B
Bnk instance A
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main2.py", line 13, in <module>
    exec(code)
  File "A.py", line 4, in <module>
    from B import B
  File "C:\Users\mc\Desktop\ImportTest\Src\B.py", line 1, in <module>
    B = Bnk('B')
NameError: name 'Bnk' is not defined
```

From the main, directly compile and execute B.py is fine, compile and execute the first part of A.py is also fine, which implies the interpreter already knows Bnk class, but in executing the second half of A.py, the interpreter complains the Bnk is not defined?

Comment: Every module has its own namespace. When you're importing from B, it can't access the main program's variables.

Comment: The idea is that a module should not behave differently depending on the file that's importing it.